# Linux error:No such file or directory

Tags: linux

I have written a script `abc.sh` and saved it in a place called `generallstuff`.
I navigate to this folder with:

```
cd ~ /generallstuff
```

when i try to run the script with:

```
chmod 755 abc.sh
```

i get the error `"no such file or directory"`

But the script is in this place, why is this. Previously i had no problem running scripts

Comment: `chmod 755 abc.sh` does not execute the script but will set the appropriate permissions for the file. When does the error happen? With `chmod 755 abc.sh` or after you tried to run the script?

Comment: Did you do `cd ~/generalstuff` instead of `cd ~ /generalstuff` ?

Comment: i had forgotten the / in the execute command

Comment: @JohnnyWilliem You mean you left out the `/` in part in my answer where I mention how to run the script?

Answer (score 7):

`cd ~ /generallstuff` should be `cd ~/generallstuff`, otherwise you will change into your home directory instead.

Answer (score 6):

***Where/When*** exactly does the error message show up?

A couple of things to check:

(1) The `chmod` command makes the script *only* executable, it does *not* run it. `chmod +x abc.sh` will make your script executable.

> **Aside**: I much prefer the "human readable" version of the `chmod`
>   command to the one using octal notation. So for instance:
>
> `chmod u+x file`   means change file for user to executable (or just
>   `+x`, the `u`ser is implied by default).
>
> You can specify `g`roup, `o`thers in place of `u`, or combinations. In
>   place of `x` you can use `w`, `r` etc, again in combinations if wanted
>
> Use `+` to add, `-` to take away attributes.
>
> See the [chmod man page](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) for more
>   information.

(2) Do you have the appropriate shell incantation at the top of your shell file? e.g.,

```
 #!/bin/bash
```

(or whichever shell you want)

(3) How are you running it? This way should work:

```
./abc.sh
```

(4) **Note**: Your `cd` command has a *space* `(' '`) between the `~` and `/generallstuff` .. hopefully that's just a typo in the posting; otherwise, the command will *fail* and you won't change directories!

Comment: On `chmod`: it depends on the initial permissions of the file. Generally a user created file has: `-rw-rw-r--`. **+x** will change this to `-rwxrwxr-x` = 775. 755 is usually seen on non-Linux systems, where the group name is different from user name. Use the `stat` command to compare numeric and human-readable formats.