# -ksh: revenue_ext.ksh: not found [No such file or directory]

Tags: shell-script, ksh, executable

I am getting the same `not found [No such file or directory]` error when trying to execute a ksh script. Read tips about the PATH and running the script with a `./` in the posts [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40831/linux-errorno-such-file-or-directory) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91699/no-such-file-or-directory-on-files-that-exist) and tried but no luck. The script does exist under the directory from where I am trying to execute and has full permissions but gives the same error when run directly or with a `./`. The first line within the script also has `#!/usr/bin/ksh`

The error message is like below:

```
-ksh: revenue_ext.ksh: not found [No such file or directory]
```

However, other `ksh` scripts under the same directory run fine so am absolutely clueless about what could be wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the output of `cat -v revenue_ext.ksh`?

Comment: If you have moved this file from windows to unix
Then run **dos2unix filename filename** command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe there may be some carriage returns causing this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19846806/1742825). I was able to reproduce the error successfully.

**Testing**

```
cat ksh_experiment.ksh

#!/usr/bin/ksh
echo "Hello"
```

Now after providing the permissions when I ran the file, it produced the output successfully. Now as discussed over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7742437/1742825), I inserted some carriage returns in my file. Now when I ran the script, I was getting the output as,

```
ksh: ./ksh_experiment.ksh: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Now, `cat -v ksh_experiment.ksh` too produced the same output. Also, if I typed `vim ksh_experiment.ksh` , a new file was getting opened.

As discussed in the answer of the link that I provided, I removed the carriage returns using the command,

```
 perl -p -i -e "s/\r//g" ksh_experiment.ksh
```

After fixing when I ran, I got the output as expected.

Comment: Yes you are right.There were ^M characters within the file that were not easily visible to the naked eye. Gave dos2unix revenue_ext.ksh and it worked:)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this same error message come up if the file is either *.ksh* or *.sh* like this:

```
-ksh: ./somefile.sh: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Turns out its the access issue.

Even though you make this file executable, on the server you might need admin rights to run. I could run command line, but executing the script would return not found, try  run the script in *sudo*, then you will know if you are allowed to run the script as root or not.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to `^M` characters.

Try using `dos2unix <File_name>` and we should be okay to get expected results.

Comment: this was mentionned in comment of accepted answer. Note to moderator: new commers won't see multiple deleted answer recomending `dos2unix` I suggest we keep one opened.