# What is the ^M character called?

Tags: character-encoding, text

TexPad is creating it.
I know that it is under some deadkey.
I just cannot remember it is name.

The blue character:

[image]

I just want to mass remove them from my document.

**How can you type it?**

Comment: Related: [Why are special characters such as “carriage return” represented as “^M”?](http://superuser.com/q/763879/53590) on Super User.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It is known as carriage return.

If you're using `vim` you can enter insert mode and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>. That **^M** is the keyboard equivalent to **\r**.

Inserting `0x0D` in a hex editor will do the task.

**How do I remove it?**

You can remove it using the command

```
perl -p -i -e "s/\r//g" filename
```

As the OP suggested in the comments of this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134582/47538), you can even try a `

```
dos2unix filename
```

and see if that fixes it.

As @steeldriver suggests in the comments, after opening the vim editor, press <kbd>esc</kbd> key and type `:set ff=unix`.

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585449/insert-the-carriage-return-character-in-vim

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7742437/1742825

[-ksh: revenue_ext.ksh: not found [No such file or directory]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134581/not-found-no-such-file-or-directory-error-on-linux-machine)

Comment: Thanks, @Ramesh. I have no idea how to do those  keyboard codes. You're a good guy.

Comment: @mikeserv, use <kbd> key </kbd> to use the keyboard symbols. :)

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question "what is it called"

Answer (score 8):

Code

```
sed -i 's/^M//' filename.txt
```

While typing `^M` in the command, do not use <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> as that only inserts what is displayed, not what causes it to be displayed; use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

you can also do this with sed

```
 sed -i "s/\r//g" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ramesh notes, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> should get you the literal character - though you're not limited to doing this only in `vim` - you should be able to do the same on any canonical mode tty.

```
cat ./file | tr -d '\r' >./file
```

...might do the job.

Comment: you're reading from and writing to the same file, would this not cause a problem

Comment: @1_CR Im reading from the `|pipe` file. Its true, an intermediate tmp file would be more robust - but the buffer in the pipe should be enough. Still, in case it isnt, `tr -d '\r' <<FILE >./file\n$(cat ./file)\nFILE\n` would be a sure thing - provided the file contains no `\000` characters, that is.

Comment: This will more than likely erase `./file` before `cat` has a chance to read it. All commands of a pipeline are launched in parallel and redirections are processed by the shell **before** the affected command is executed.

Comment: @mikeserv re the heredoc-containing-`$(cat)` fix: or (significant) trailing empty lines or unterminated last line, or more data than fits in available memory. `(rm file; tr -d '\r' >file) <file` avoids those, if recreating the file is okay (resets owner/group/permbits/ACL/context/etc)