# FreeBSD move folders from a list

Tags: shell-script, scripting, freebsd, mv, move

I have a `.txt` file that has a list of folders I would like to move from one directory to another. I have seen many posts on this, but none have worked. Mostly because those are using GNU versions of `mv` and `xargs`.  I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/538306/move-a-list-of-filesin-a-text-file-to-a-directory) post that is doing what I want but only in Linux. Currently, we are using the latest version of TrueNAS Core which is running FreeBSD version 12.2-RELEASE-p3

I tried using the code below, the folder names in the file have letters, numbers, spaces, `(`, and `)`:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do 
    mv Projects/"$file" Archives/PROJECT\ ARCHIVE\ 2020; 
done < Projects/Archive_List_test.txt
```

It gives me this output:

```
 to Archives/PROJECT ARCHIVE 2020/folder1: No such file or directory
: No such file or directoryE 2020/folder2
```

folder1 and folder2 are the folder names that are in the list. For my test, I only have 2 folders, but I actually need to move over about 360 folders

Thank you for your time.

Comment: that overlap between the error message and filename indicates a carriage-return issue, see e.g. : https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134695/170373 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/372672/what-could-cause-a-script-to-fail-to-find-python-when-it-has-usr-bin-env-pyt/372691#372691

Comment: Try quotes around "Archives/PROJECT\ ARCHIVE\ 2020" - notice you're not trying a drectory name "E", i.e,. one the "E" in on the filenames is creating the error "directoryE".

Comment: @CinaedSimson It looks like it gives me the same error.

Comment: Okay, but you shouldn't put a slash and qutes. Where is the "read" command coming from? And are you sure the errors aren't coming from the "Projects/Archive_List_test.txt"?

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The script below seems to be working as expected. Let's test the folders below

```bsh
admin@truenas:~/tmp $ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  4 admin  admin    6 Apr  2 14:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 admin  admin   12 Apr  2 14:06 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 admin  admin   16 Apr  2 14:18 Archive_List_test.txt
drwxr-xr-x  3 admin  admin    3 Apr  2 14:07 Archives
drwxr-xr-x  4 admin  admin    4 Apr  2 14:19 Projects
-rwxr-xr-x  1 admin  admin  130 Apr  2 14:17 script.sh
```

```bsh
admin@truenas:~/tmp $ ls -la Archives/PROJECT\ ARCHIVE\ 2020 
total 1
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  admin  2 Apr  2 14:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 admin  admin  3 Apr  2 14:07 ..
```

```bsh
admin@truenas:~/tmp $ ls -la Projects/
total 14
drwxr-xr-x  4 admin  admin  4 Apr  2 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 admin  admin  6 Apr  2 14:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  admin  2 Apr  2 14:19 folder 1
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  admin  2 Apr  2 14:19 folder 2
```

```bsh
admin@truenas:~/tmp $ cat Archive_List_test.txt 
folder 1
folder 2
```

This script moves the folders, listed in file *Archive_List_test.txt*, from the directory *Projects/* to the directory *Archives/PROJECT\ ARCHIVE\ 2020/*

```bsh
admin@truenas:~/tmp $ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r file; do 
    mv "Projects/${file}" Archives/PROJECT\ ARCHIVE\ 2020/; 
done <Archive_List_test.txt
```

```bsh
admin@truenas:~/tmp $ ./script.sh 
admin@truenas:~/tmp $ ls -la Projects/
total 13
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  admin  2 Apr  2 14:30 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 admin  admin  6 Apr  2 14:15 ..
admin@truenas:~/tmp $ ls -la Archives/PROJECT\ ARCHIVE\ 2020 
total 2
drwxr-xr-x  4 admin  admin  4 Apr  2 14:30 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 admin  admin  3 Apr  2 14:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  admin  2 Apr  2 14:19 folder 1
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  admin  2 Apr  2 14:19 folder 2
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! When I test out what you have I get the same error. Could it be because instead of `folder1` and 2 it is actually like `13 folder test 1` and `14 folder (test) 2`. Could those spaces be what is making it not be able to find the correct folders?

Comment: You're welcome! Quote the source, e.g. `"Projects/${file}"`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working for me. When I `cat` my `Archive_List_test.txt` file, at the end of it I am getting a random `#`. That is not in my file with the list of folders. Might I need to strip off some special characters or something?