# Shell script not executing

Tags: shell, ksh, executable

Not sure what is happening.

Lets call script `a.sh` with the following

```
/users/guru$ cat a.sh
#! /usr/bin/ksh

echo "Hello"
date
```

Execute with `ksh`. It gets done.

```
/users/guru$ ksh a.sh
Hello
Tue Jul 15 15:00:52 EDT 2014
```

Ensure file permission and `ksh` path.

```
/users/guru$ ls -l a.sh
-rwxrwxrwx    1 guru  kpc         35 Jul 15 15:00 a.sh
/users/guru$ a.sh
ksh: a.sh:  not found
/users/guru$ which ksh
/usr/bin/ksh
```

Comment: Sometimes it is possible to have whitespaces which might cause the error. See the answer to this question here. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134581/ksh-revenue-ext-ksh-not-found-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: The following command fixed it: add ``export PATH=$PATH:.`` to users ``.profile``

Comment: See my other comment about why `PATH=$PATH:.` is considered harmful.

Comment: Thanks, Richard. It helps. However, I would ask for more reasons/detials, I do not agree a mere filename-command-conflict warrant banning inclusion of "." to PATH altogether. Simply, I would never name my scripts as a keyword (or ensure "." is at the end of path).

Answer (score 8):

Try "./a.sh" when trying to execute it.  It needs to know where the file is at.

The './' tells it to look in the current directory.

Comment: +1 OK. ``./`` does the trick. But why so? I should be able to execute the script as such calling the file?

Comment: Shell environments have an environment variable called "PATH" (echo $PATH), if the script you are executing is not within the $PATH, then it won't know where to look.  If you want to make it executable from anywhere try putting it in a directory in the path, or add a directory to it, where you keep your scripts.

Comment: It used to be common practice to have `.` in the `PATH`, but then it was realised that it was a security risk, so it was removed. Imagine . being at start of `PATH`. Then a local script called `ls` could intercept calls to `ls`. If `.` is but at the end of `PATH`, then you install package that has a program with conflicting name the this program is run instead of the one you expect. (You may notice that in `cmd` on ms-windows `.` is implicitly in the `PATH`, this could be considered a bug in `cmd`, as it can not be changed. You may also note that ms-windows has more virus problems.

Answer (score 4):

When you type a command, the shell looks up the command from a list of directories, as specified by the `PATH` variable.

The current directory is not in `PATH` by default (for security reason), so the shell can not find your script.

Using `./`, meaning the current directory, so the shell knows where is your script.

Comment: So, add "." to path and export path? I can use ./ but want to know why can't we run the script as such.

Comment: Yes, add `PATH=$PATH:.` in your `.bashrc`, and remember to do it for **TESTING** only.

Comment: @Guru You cant run it as such because the directory the script is located in is not in the PATH. Executing `a.sh` will only work if it can be found in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

As I have posted in the other question, sometimes it is possible to get the file not found error even when you execute the script as `./scriptname`. As I have posted in the other [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134582/47538), you can test it in your machine.

**Testing**

```
cat ksh_experiment.ksh

#!/usr/bin/ksh
echo "Hello"
```

Now after providing the permissions when I ran the file, it produced the output successfully. Now as discussed over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7742437/1742825), I inserted some carriage returns in my file. Now when I ran the script, I was getting the output as,

```
ksh: ./ksh_experiment.ksh: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Now, `cat -v ksh_experiment.ksh` too produced the same output. Also, if I typed `vim ksh_experiment.ksh` , a new file was getting opened.

As discussed in the answer of the link that I provided, I removed the carriage returns using the command,

```
 perl -p -i -e "s/\r//g" ksh_experiment.ksh
```

After fixing when I ran, I got the output as expected.

Now, you can use `dos2unix` as well to convert the file.